# Can't debug using eclipse and weblogic 8.1 ( weblogic 10 works fine)

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic8.x

first of all, Is it possible to debug web apps with eclipse and weblogic 8.1.
I can successfully debug with weblogic 10.
in weblogic 8.1 when I click on debug server from eclipse it shows me a debugging warning about debugging jsp pages. and then starts. when It start, the server state shows in eclipse as "started" not debug compared to weblogic 10 and break points dont work at all.

I did set up my startWLS.cmd file correctly for debugging.
I m using eclipse 3.4

Comment: you may find it easier to debug your weblogic using a sun jvm instead of jrockit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using some kind of plugin to eclipse that allows you to debug code running on weblogic without being notified about the gory details of the process.

Actually what happens is that your are running weblogic as external process (even if you see its stdout into the eclipse console) and connect to it with remote debugger.

So, probably your plugin does not support weblogic 8.

But it is very simple to debug any java application remotely.

The following article describes how to do this: http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Shortly you have to add the following options when your run your application:

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y`

Just find the bat/cmd/sh script that runs weblogic and modify it.

Then start remote debugging by Run/Debug Configurations/Remote Java Application

and configure the port your specified when your ran your application.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is cool site, but you will likely get more on-topic responses to your question by asking it on Oracle's eclipse tooling forum:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=578